# Downloading source on web

Tags: web, datasource

where are source documents downloading to when I start a site ?
ram or disk ?
like this

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Most of the browsers will save it to disk temporarily. If the http headers enables caching of these resources, then it will store permanently (or it will flush after certain period). Using incognito mode will store most (not all) things in ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external JavaScript files live on the server. When the browser requests them, the browser retrieves the file, downloads it in the client's hard disk, and then executes it locally.